# another mysql minus question

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
SELECT id, name FROM t_profiles MINUS (SELECT p.id, p.name FROM t_profiles AS p LEFT JOIN t_skills AS s ON p.id = s.id_employee WHERE s.lvl>0 and s.id_task=1)
```

Is there an easy way to do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name FROM t_profiles 
WHERE id not in 
   (SELECT p.id FROM t_profiles AS p 
    LEFT JOIN t_skills AS s ON p.id = s.id_employee 
    WHERE s.lvl>0 and s.id_task=1)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: 10 years later , I would say this is not a correct answer.  The question is to substract sets based on 2 fields not 1.  Concat them or use left join / not null.

Comment: well, it seems to have helped OP back then, @ninjabber . But if you disagree, why not post an alternative answer? While it probably won't make it into OP's codebase any more, stackoverflow is a repository of answers for many people, and even old questions and answers get found (q.e.d.'ed by yourself) and will help people today and in future.

Comment: Had a quick look and decided it’s wrong without finishing reading the entire question. The answer is correct and my previous comment is wrong!